# Getting only retweeted posts from Twitter api

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to get sample tweets from the twitter api that are only retweets? I know you can track users and track keywords, like "Twitter" but is there a way to track tweets which have been retweeted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The "retweeted" and "retweeted_status" properties of the [tweet object](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) are what you want to look at.